# Avr-gcc using repeated addition instead of MULU instructions

Tags: avr, c++, avr-gcc, multiplication

I recently compiled some C++ code for the [ATmega1284P](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATmega1284p) in Atmel Studio and was analyzing the timings of some routines using my scope. To my surprise, a loop I thought I had optimized was taking longer than expected.

After taking a peek at the assembly code, I noticed that the compiler has compiled the following multiplication:

```
word *= 10;
```

into repeated addition:

```
add    r28, r28
adc    r29, r29
add    r18, r18
adc    r19, r19
add    r18, r18
adc    r19, r19
add    r18, r18
adc    r19, r19
add    r18, r28
adc    r19, r29
```

Now although I admire the optimizations in this repeated addition, there is no reason to do so when the chip has hardware multiplication instructions available, like `mul`.

[image: 1284P hardware multiplication supported]

Why is gcc behaving this way and how can I tell it to use hardware multiplication instructions? Note that I have set up the multiplication so overflow is not an issue. `word` is a uint16_t.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Assuming that you want to optimize for speed:

Unless you really find out how many cycles it takes if you use `mul`, you can't compare.

So let’s try:

- If you use the `mul` instruction, you need two of them (the operand is 16 bit). So that already costs **4** cycles.
- You have to load constant 10 into one register: **1** cycle.
- Then you have to add both 16 bit results. That costs another **2** cycles.
- Then you have to consider, that the results of both `mul`s always go into register pair r1:r0, but in order to add both results you have to move one of them to some other place: that costs **2** more cycles.

So that makes it already 4 + 1 + 2 + 2 = **9** cycles, just one cycle less than what you got with repeated addition, but you've used more registers. That alone may justify repeated addition (depending on what else is done, having used one more register may cost you more than one cycle).

EDIT:
The calculation above was a back-of-the-envelope calculation; further analysis (cf. 2012rcampion's answer) shows that moving a register pair can be done in 1 cycle (there's a special instruction) and for adding the two multiplication results one add is enough (because we are not interested in a full 3 byte result but want to do a wrap-around with 16-bit width); on the other hand additional measures are required: e.g. clearing the zero register (I guess r0).
Note also that the variant with `mul` uses much more registers: 7 instead of only 4; a high price because it may cause several more cycles (and code size) at other places.

Comment: Ahah! The fact that the value is stored in a r1:r0 escaped me. That makes sense for a multiply-by 10 being optimized down to additions. I tried multiplying by 100 and it used mul's like I expected. Marked as accepted.

Comment: Ten additions still seems less than optimal, wouldn't 5 additions followed by an ROR be better?

Comment: It seems to be more complicated than 10 simple additions. Four registers are involved. Is it ((2*(2*word)) + 1*word)*2?

Comment: Glen Yates: Perhaps because the registers are 8-bit registers? (Not a rhetorical question)

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Yep, it looks like each `add`+`adc` pair is a single 16 bit addition. So what the assembly code quoted by the OP seems to be doing is calculating `2 * word` (one doubling) and `8 * word` (three doublings) and then adding them together. Five 16 bit additions all together. (It also seems to assume that the original value of `word` is found both in `r18`/`r19` and in `r28`/ `r29`. Presumably that's ensured by something before the quoted code that the OP left out.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks, my assembly experience is from a different platform and of course I meant LSL and ROL instead of right shifts and rolls.

Comment: @PeterMortensen this is correct, and that's another reason why multiplying by ten is more efficiently done this way. Ten additions would take more cycles than mul.

Answer (score 4):

I can't tell you why GCC is doing the multiply this way, but I can tell you that it is not faster than using `mul`.  I used the the [datasheet](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATmega1284P) (section 33) to count the number of cycles the following routine takes (AVR-GCC 9.2.0, [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/PcTroPz7c)):

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint16_t times_ten(uint16_t word) {
    return word * 10;
}
```

For `-O1` through `-O3` (optimize for speed):

```
movw r18,r24 ; 1 cycle 
lsl r18      ; 1
rol r19      ; 1
lsl r18      ; 1
rol r19      ; 1
add r24,r18  ; 1
adc r25,r19  ; 1
lsl r24      ; 1
rol r25      ; 1
             ; 9 total
```

Note the combination of `lsl` and `rol` to multiply a register pair by two is the same speed as adding a register pair to itself with `add` and `adc` as shown in the question (2 cycles and 2 instructions).

And for `-Os` (optimize for code size):

```
ldi r18,lo8(10)  ; 1
movw r20,r24     ; 1
mul r18,r20      ; 2
movw r24,r0      ; 1
mul r18,r21      ; 2
add r25,r0       ; 1
clr __zero_reg__ ; 1
                 ; 9 total
```

Interestingly, both methods take the same number of cycles, and using `mul` uses fewer instructions.  In fact, done multiple times as part of a larger function where 10 can be saved in a register and zeroing r1 can be deferred until the end, using `mul` would be two cycles faster!

Comment: Interesting... I have considered moving to Atmelcrochip's new IDE, which has an improved compiler and the extra option to pay some enormous fee for 'revolutionary optimizations.' Perhaps being a little more intelligent with multiplication is one of those perks, but I think I'll stick with my additions for now...

Comment: Note that the variant without `mul` uses only **4** registers (r18, r19, r24, r25) while the variant with `mul` uses **7** registers (r0, r1, r18, r20, r21, r24, r25); a big disadvantage of the latter.

Comment: @Hackstaar: The revolutionary optimizations from Microchip are: They are disabling optimizations avr-gcc would perform, and make you pay for the version that has them enabled. Better stick with a complier not "improved" by Microchip. For the optimization in question though, it's what avr-gcc does per default, and it matches its cost computation: It doesn't see the `movw` in the `-O3` version because that it introduced by the register allocator, which runs much later than instruction selection.

Comment: For AVR GCC 9.2.0 -mmcu=avr25 -Os, I get a short `ldi r22,lo8(10)  ldi r23,0  rcall __mulhi3  ret`. (Why `rcall  ret` instead of just `rjmp`?!)

Answer (score 2):

> Why is gcc behaving this way?

So why? Let's have a look at the cost computation in [`gcc/config/avr/avr.cc:avr_rtx_costs()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/config/avr/avr.cc;h=a297f4e092a8a89f50de0649d91f63423b4f09eb;hb=951a3e3749a9bf15cea3940ad4bd76d696e1b0b6#l11677):

```
    case E_HImode:
      if (AVR_HAVE_MUL)
        {
          rtx op0 = XEXP (x, 0);
          rtx op1 = XEXP (x, 1);
          ...

          if (...)
            ...
          else if (register_operand (op0, HImode)
                   && (u8_operand (op1, HImode)
                       || s8_operand (op1, HImode)))
            {
              *total = COSTS_N_INSNS (!speed ? 6 : 9);
              return true;
            }
```

This is the cost for multiplication of a 16-bit integral value with an 8-bit compile-time constant (signed or unsigned). The costs are:

- 9 (in unity of ticks) when compiling for speed,
- 6 (in units of words) otherwise, e.g. when compiling for size.

Such a sequence would read something like

```lisp
    ldi  R_ten,     10     ; 1
    mul  R_in.lo8,  R_ten  ; 2
    movw R_OUT,     R0     ; 1
    mul  R_IN.hi8,  R_ten  ; 2
    add  R_OUT.hi8, R0     ; 1
    clr __zero_reg__       ; 1
```

where the output register must not overlap with any of the input registers.  The actual costs are 6 words and 8 ticks, and to me it is not completely clear why avr-gcc is using 9 ticks in the cost model.  Such penalty would usually account for costs that are not visible at that stage, like high register pressure or additional moves forced by early-clobber. And indeed, the real sequence has a superfluous move instruction and actually costs 9 ticks...

Where are the costs of the shift+add sequence? They are not visible here. The costs are used during instruction selection when lowering tree-[SSA](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/SSA.html) to [RTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_transfer_language). The middle-end knows some algorithms to expand mul-with-const and will add costs for the required operations: (3 * shift + 1 * add) * 2 bytes = 8 ticks.

**So shift+add appears cheaper than MUL.**  Tree-SSA → RTL lowering takes place<sup>3</sup> in pass 234 out of 316, and costs due to register allocation (like spills, reloads or moves) are not available because reg alloc takes place later, at pass 280 / 316.

---

> and how can I tell it to use hardware multiplication instructions?

There is no such option. Instruction selection follows from the device familiy, which follows from `-mmcu=...`. If you insist on using `MUL`, you'd have to use inline assembly like for example:

```
__attribute__((__always_inline__))
static inline uint16_t mul_u16_u8 (uint16_t a, uint8_t b)
{
#if defined __AVR_HAVE_MUL__
    uint16_t result;
    __asm ("mul  %A[in16], %[in8]"  "\n\t"
           "movw %[res], r0"        "\n\t"
           "mul  %B[in16], %[in8]"  "\n\t"
           "add  %B[res], r0"       "\n\t"
           "clr  __zero_reg__"
           : [res] "=&r" (result)
           : [in16] "r" (a), [in8] "r" (b));
    return result;
#else
    return a * b;
#endif
}

uint16_t use_mul_u16_u8 (uint16_t x)
{
    return mul_u16_u8 (x, 10);
}
```

The inline squence takes 7 ticks, and setting `b = 10` takes one more tick.  Assuming no other instructions are required<sup>2</sup>, it consumes 8 ticks. The final `CLR` is required due to avr-gcc ABI, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59965284/1556746).

What **does not work** though is something like

```
__attribute__((__optimize__("Os"), __always_inline__))
static inline uint16_t mul_Os (uint16_t a, uint8_t b)
{
    return a * b;
}

uint16_t use_mul_Os (uint16_t x)
{
    return mul_Os (x, 10);
}
```

and compile with `-O2`. Inlining takes place prior to instructio selection, and even though GCC annotates every RTL insn whether to optimize for size or speed, it doesn't work out here (dunno if that could be considered a GCC problem).

---

**Footnotes**

<sup>2</sup>For the test case, the assumption does not hold because the output operand of the asm is [early clobber](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Modifiers.html), and both result and 1st input will occupy R25:R24, hence at least one more `MOVW` is needed.

<sup>3</sup>Using pass numbers from avr-gcc v8.